# chown does not give me any right

Tags: chmod, chown

I have a folder, `my-folder`.
From its parent directory, I first do:

```
sudo chown -cR matthewslouismarie: my-folder
```

If I then do: `chmod -cR 600 my-folder`, I get:

```
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/build.sh': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/vmdk': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/.git': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/run.sh': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/docker': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'my-folder/.gitignore': Permission denied
```

Am I not supposed to fully own this folder and its content?

Notes:

Running `sudo chmod -cR 600 my-folder` does not print anything. `matthewslouismarie` is what I get when I type `whoami`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @andyDalton says you need `x` (execute) permissions to look in a directory.

Therefore you could set permission to `700` however that will set `x` on regular file.

If you have gnu `chmod`, then you can use symbolic mode:

```
chmod -cR u+rwX my-folder
```

This will only **add** to the **user** permission, and will only add `x` if it as a directory or already exists on group or other.

Also consider if you need to use `chmod`. It may already be how you want it. `chown` does not reset it.

Comment: Seems to be perfect! It only adds the execute flag if it's a directory right?

Comment: `+X` adds `x` to directories or to files that already have `x` set somewhere else (in u,g, or o).

Answer (score 4):

The `x` permission on directories is what controls whether or not a user can traverse into that directory.  By using mode `600`, you've removed the `x` bit, and therefore cannot traverse into the directory.

Try this:

```
find my-folder -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

That will change the permissions for the various directories back to `700` (`rwx------`).  If you want files to be `600`, similarly, you could do:

```
find my-folder -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```